# What Exactly Happens to TableRows on Postback?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a table inside of an update panel that is supposed to refresh every 5 seconds. `lblDate` is set when the UpdatePanel refreshes. `lblAddress` is set on Page Load. Both appear to be working fine.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlreport" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:Table ID="tblReport" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddress" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="tmrUpdate" Interval="5000" OnTick="tmrUpdate_Tick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Every time the table refreshes, I add rows to the table.

```
    protected void tmrUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the timestamp on the report
        lblDate = DateTime.Now.toString();
        setupTables();
        tmrUpdate.Interval = 5000; // Reset the timer
    }
```

The function `setupTables()` is where I clear any data that was in the tables and then add the newest data back to the table. But I want to leave the two hardcoded rows intact because they serve as a sort of "header". This is where I have a problem.

```
protected void setupTables(ServiceStatus data)
{
    // Clear all but the header rows
    for (int i = 2; i < tblReport.Rows.Count; i++) 
        tblReport.Rows.RemoveAt(i); // A breakpoint here never gets hit.

    // Populate the table with new rows
    TableRow fakeDataRow = new TableRow();

    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "Fake text for Cell 1";
    fakeDataRow.Cells.Add(tc)

    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.Text = "Fake text for Cell 2";
    fakeDataRow.Cells.Add(tc)

    tblReport.Rows.Add(fakeDataRow);
}
```

On postback, I noticed that the `for` loop that clears out the old rows never got hit. My table clearly has three rows after the addition of my fake one, but it simply disappears on postback. So I added this line to see what was going on.

```
fakeDataRow.ID = "trFakeData";
```

However, the page throws an error like "An item with the same key has already been added" after the second refresh. If there is already a row with that key, where did it go, and how can I properly remove it?

Comment: Your definition of table has 2 rows with 1 cell each. But in your method setupTables(), you're adding a row with 2 cells? Also, I am not sure if you didn't provide the complete code but the "row" object on where you're removing the row is not defined anywhere.

Comment: during which page lifecycle event are the two header rows added? (Page Init, Load, etc.)

Comment: @pinoy_ISF The cells in the rows with only 1 cell have a column span of 2. The cells in row added in the code behind have a column span of 1 (at least I assume that is the default). With regard to the latter half of your comment: Sorry about that. A little bit of code got lost in translation. Do you see where I removed the row now?

Comment: @ps2goat They are hardcoded in the aspx file. You can see where I declared them in the HTML block of code at the top of the question.

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Comment: @ps2goat It occurs after all of my code has finished executing. I watched it line by line. The exception doesn't contain a line number anywhere that I can see. It just says that I have two items with the same key. I assume that it is referring to trFakeData. But trFakeData isn't in the tblReport.Rows collection, so I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Don't you need to set updatemode on the updatepanel to always?

Comment: @JonH Always is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Your looping and indexing as it is will get messed up if you loop over elements and remove indexes as you are (you'd have to do it in reverse in order to not mess it up, e.g., start at count - 1 and do i--).

```
protected void setupTables(ServiceStatus data)
{
    // Clear all but the header rows
    TableRow header1 = tblReport.Rows[0];
    TableRow header2 = tblReport.Rows[1];

    tblReport.Rows.Clear();

    tblReport.Rows.Add(header1);
    tblReport.Rows.Add(header2);

    //... the rest of your logic to add fake data...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I modified the collection I was iterating over while I was iterating over it. I feel pretty dumb. You obviously returned here to ask relevant questions repeatedly before coming to this answer, and for that I thank you. Tested and works like a charm.